# Confusion regarding a relationship that involves the radian measure.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've stumbled across something whilst reading online and it's confusing to me:

> In any circle there is a specific angle where the radius is equal 
>   to the arc length. This angle is defined as one radian and is
>   approximately equal to 57.29 degrees.
>
> **From this it can then be said that for every length of arc that is
>   equal to the radius there is 1 radian of angle subtended. For any
>   sector the angle will be so many lots of 1 radian, and thus the arc
>   length will be the same number of times of the radius. From this you
>   can then write:**
>
> $\frac{\text {arc length}}{\text{angle in radians}} = \frac{\text{radius}}{\text{1 radian}}$

---

I understand what is said in the paragaph in bold, but what I don't understand is ***HOW*** it leads to the relationship that is set up afterwards, could someone break this down and explain each side of the equation to me. Thank you.

Comment: To achieve the formula for both sides, I think you can view it as arc length is directly proportional to radius. In my opinion, the statement in bold is a little misleading. It seems as if that only one can have a natural number (counting number) or at best rational number of times of 1 radian. If that is the case, what is the meaning of $2\pi$ times of radian, since $2\pi$ is irrational?

Comment: Suggest you get a very round wheel of some kind that can be laid on the ground sideways, and has a very evident outer edge (old time wagon wheel would work). Then mark a beginning point and get a rope cut to exactly the radius. Then wrap the rope around the circumference and make a second mark where the rope ends. Then do the same for some other wheel of obviously different radius. Take notes. In general, when the brain cannot work something out, see if there is something for the hands to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alternative definition of radian measure may help you understand the equation.

**Definition.**  The *radian measure* of a central angle of a circle with radius $r$ subtended by an arc of length $s$ is $$\theta = \frac{s}{r} \tag{1}$$

[image: definition_of_radian_measure]

Since both $s$ and $r$ are lengths, the units (say meters) cancel out.  Therefore, radians are dimensionless.

When the arc length is equal to the radius of the circle, then 
$$\theta = \frac{s}{r} = \frac{r}{r} = 1$$

If we solve equation 1 for $r$, we obtain $$r = \frac{s}{\theta}\tag{2}$$

Observe that we can write equation 2 in the form

$$\frac{s}{\theta} = \frac{r}{1}\tag{3}$$

Equation 3 states that the ratio of the length, $s$, of an arc that subtends a central angle to the radian measure, $\theta$, of that angle is equal to the ratio of the length of an arc whose length is equal to the radius, $r$, of the circle to a central angle with measure $1$ radian.

The author of your text has written equation 3 in the form

$$\frac{\text{arc length}}{\text{radian measure}} = \frac{\text{radius}}{1~\text{radian}}$$

The author of your text is defining $1$ radian to be the measure of a central angle of a circle subtended by an arc of length equal to its radius, then arguing that since the arc length is proportional to the measure of the central angle that equation 3 must hold.  Given the author's phrasing, it might have made more sense to write $$\frac{s}{r} = \frac{\theta}{1}$$ from which equation 3 can be derived by multiplying both sides of the equation by $r/\theta$.

Had I written your text, I would have used the definition of radian measure I gave above, then derived the fact that a central angle of measure 1 radian is subtended by an arc of length equal to the radius of the circle.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a Euclidian plane, a circular sector with radius r and arc-length s, has a vertex angle, theta, proportional to s and inversely proportional to r--this results from axioms defining Euclidian space.  We thus have:

theta = const (s/r)

Since the dimension of theta is plane angle, say A, and s/r is dimensionless, the dimension of const is A--i.e. const is an angle.  We can easily evaluate const by setting s = 2 pi r, corresponding to theta = rev (an angle consisting of one complete revolution, which is easily conceptualized):

rev = const (2 pi r)/r = (2 pi) const

So:

const = rev/(2 pi)

note that this is dimensionally consistent--the equation has the dimension A.

We give this important constant a special name: one radian, symbol rad.  Thus:

rad = rev/(2 pi)

and we now have (THE FUNDAMENTAL EQUATION):

theta = (s/r) rad,

We can get a feeling for the angle represented by rad by setting s = r:

theta(s=r) = (r/r) rad = rad

i.e. one radian is the vertex angle of a circular sector in which the arc-length equals the radius (a well-known definition--with a well-known diagram).

Now, what is usually called the "angle in radians" or the "radian measure of the angle" is actually the *number of radians in theta*, theta/rad:

radian measure (of theta) = theta/rad = s/r

The *number* of radians in theta (being a number) is dimensionless--again, the equation is dimensionally consistent.  We can rewrite the fundamental equation, "theta = (s/r) rad," in two other ways:

(1):   s/theta = r/rad

or

(2):   s/(theta/rad) = r/1

In words:

(1):   (arc-length)/(angle) = (radius)/(one radian)

Note that the denominator on the left is angle--NOT "angle in radians."

(2):   (arc-length)/("angle in radians") = (radius)/(one)

Note that the denominator on the right is one--NOT one radian.

Unfortunately, in many textbooks (and in the SI definition), the dimensionless quantity theta/rad is called (plane) "angle."  It is (obviously) not an angle at all--it is the number of radians in the angle theta.  If we give theta/rad the symbol theta*, the fundamental equation becomes:

theta* = s/r

This is the form seen in (most) textbooks and on-line tutorials--with theta* called an "angle" (and without the warning asterisk), but with the stipulation that the "angle" must be "expressed in radians" or in "radian measure."  The former is incomplete: the "angle must be expressed in radians and we must take its numerical value, theta/rad."  The term "radian measure" of course means the same thing but is (usually) never spelled out.

One further problem is that, the SI "radian" is defined as theta* when s = r--i.e., the SI "radian" is the "number of (real) radians in one (real) radian":

SI "radian" = (1 rad)/rad = 1

Thus the SI "radian" can be inserted or extracted multiplicatively, as "needed."

This is a recipe for a lot of confusion.

However, if we remember the fundamental equation:

theta = (s/r) rad

where theta is a real physical angle (not a number) and rad is a special real physical angle (not the number 1), then everything works out just fine.